# cyrus impad and recursive 'INBOX' directories

Tags: imap

I am using cyrus imapd on Fedora

The mailbox of a user is presenting a deep tree of nested INBOXes:

```
user.foo
user.foo.Apple Mail To Do
user.foo.Archives
user.foo.Archives.2011
user.foo.Deleted Messages
user.foo.Drafts
user.foo.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
user.foo.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.INBOX.Deleted Messages
[...]
```

If I delete the folder and reconstruct the mailbox the folders are re-created

```
/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/reconstruct -r -f user.foo
```

all other users are OK

Any hint on why this structure is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be some kind of bug. Which version of cyrus imap you are using?

As a quick fix, I think following should work.

Using cyradm delete those rogue mailboxes.

You can find how to use cyradm [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mimap/chapter/ch09.html#11074).

```
localhost> sam user.foo.INBOX.* cyrus d
localhost> dm user.foo.INBOX.*
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. BTW it's version 2.4.12 (default on Fedora 16)